# Recurrence Relation to a specific algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

Good evening. The past week for my course I have been learning how to calculate run-times as well as determining recurrence relations for given algorithms. I am comfortable with iterative algs, but not recursive algorithms. Especially when there are two recursive calls that take place one after the other.

For example:

```
FindMin(int A[], int front, int last)

if (last-front <= 1) 
  return A[front]
else {
  midpoint = (front+last)/2
  int minFront = FindMin(A, front, midpoint)
  minLast =  FindMin(A, midpoint+1, last)
  return min{minFront, minLast}
}
```

If someone could help me determine the recurrence relation for this function/a function similar to it, and guide me through the steps to determining the relation, I will kiss your boots (not really, but your help will be very much appreciated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recursion is described by simple dependence, because you divide task by two equal subtasks and execute constant number of operations:

```
T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + C
T(n) = 2 * (2 * T(n/4) + C) + C = 4 * T(n/4) + 3*C
T(n) = 4 * (2 * T(n/8) + C) + 3*C = 8 * T(n/8) + 7*C
...
T(n) = n * T(1) + (n-1)*C = n * C = O(n)
```

Note that stack depth for this recursion is log(N), so space complexity is O(log(N))
(thanks to Abhishek Bansal addition)

Comment: Would be good to add as an aside that space complexity is O(logn).